# Send grid risk assessment issue

Tags: gmail-api, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid API as recommended by google in my Java Appengine app to overcome the 100 recipient quota issue, I found that it stores all emails from the sent address in its account which is a compliance issue for our organization. Is there a way to mitigate the risk ?

Is there any better option than send-grid for Appengine mails ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/) about Mail API which can send email messages to one or more recipients. All email addresses on the [Email API Authorized Senders](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings?_ga=1.16462645.2079188706.1483597746) list need to be valid Gmail or Google-hosted domain accounts. If you will be sending email from a domain managed by Google Apps, you should set the [DNS `SPF`](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33786) records for your domain to indicate that Google is a trusted source for your email. Hope this helps!

Comment: The Mail API has a 100 recipient per day quota